# Gesture based checkout for ecommerce app

Tags: e-commerce, mobile-application, checkout, gestures, swipe

We are working on a feature that allows returning customers to checkout with a gesture, since they have already given their payment and delivery info in their previous purchase.

p.s. This is for both android and ios

Here's a couple of ideas coming to mind for a interesting swipe interaction

1. User needs drag the cart icon from the top right to a delivery van visual in the center of the screen. This would be a diagonal drag from top right to the center of the screen
2. The delivery van is on the center of the screen and the user needs to swipe the van to the right.

Any comments about which is better or how it can be improved. or any ideas or interesting metaphors on how it could be done?

Comment: If the delivery van is in the centre , where will the contents be ?

Comment: a button that you TAP that says 'Buy Now'

Comment: Are you sure that swipe gesture would be as clear and fast as taping a button? Maybe you could provide some screenshots? I don't recognize the context of this solution but generally speaking I'm always trying to avoid unnecessary interaction especially if chosen solution could slow the user and could be possiblly a little vague.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to use the Answer function, but I can't add comments yet.

It's not clear from your question what platforms you're designing for, but assuming that you're designing for at least both iOS and Android I think you will have useability issues with the first option. For example, swiping from the top right on an iOS device is likely to trigger the Notifications tab.

As for option 2, it really doesn't sound intuitive to me. Wanting to provide an easy checkout option for repeat customers is a great idea, but is there a reason why you're opting for a swipe?

The most important thing is the user experience. From your question it almost appears as if form is more important than function. My suggestion is to focus on making the app easy to use (and easier for repeat customers because you've already got their details) rather than worrying about trying to implement an "interesting swipe interaction". By doing so you risk creating something that is confusing for the user.